# Yarn: How to upgrade yarn version using terminal?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, yarnpkg

How should `yarn` be upgraded to the latest version?

Answer (score 257):

For macOS users, if you installed `yarn` via `brew`, you can upgrade it using the below command:

```
brew upgrade yarn
```

On Linux, just run the below command at the terminal:

```
$ curl --compressed -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash
```

On Windows, upgrade with [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/)

```
choco upgrade yarn
```

**Credits:**
Added answers with the help of the below answers

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/54147594/842607
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/53710422/842607

Comment: tagged for Ubuntu, not MacOs.

Comment: Google does not check the tag when routing users to this question.

Comment: You can do it faster with: `(npm uninstall -g yarn && brew install yarn) || brew upgrade yarn`

Comment: Note that installing `yarn` via `brew` also installs `node`. This may be undesired if, for instance, you are using `nvm` or `n`.

Comment: @LucianoBargmann I have brew on my Linux install so it's not a bad answer for these few people who upgrade in this very way.

Comment: Using `brew` was the only thing that worked for me on OS X

Answer (score 188):

```
npm install --global yarn
npm upgrade --global yarn
```

This should work.

Comment: > Note: Installation of Yarn via npm is generally not recommended. When installing Yarn with Node-based package managers, the package is not signed, and the only integrity check performed is a basic SHA1 hash, which is a security risk when installing system-wide apps.

https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#alternatives-stable

Comment: I am pretty sure you can no longer install/upgrade yarn though `npm`, rather you need to do it throw `brew` on OSX at least.

Comment: Since this question was specifically about Ubuntu 16.04, comments about OSX and `brew` are not really relevant. I just did upgrade yarn through `npm upgrade --global yarn` on Ubuntu 16.04 where I had installed yarn through npm earlier. So pretty sure, it is still possible, even though that's not the recommended way.
My original reason for installing yarn through npm was that I'm using `nvm` to keep multiple versions of `node`. Installing yarn through `apt` would have installed a specific version of node globally. But I read this can be avoided through the parameter `--no-install-recommends`.

Comment: @mnishiguchi the page you linked does not contain the quoted text. in fact, it contains the opposite statement: "It is recommended to install Yarn through the npm package manager"

Comment: Maybe things are different now in 2021 ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I just checked Yarn website and I found this:

It is recommended to install Yarn through the npm package manager, which comes bundled with Node.js when you install it on your system.

Once you have npm installed you can run the following both to install and upgrade Yarn:

`npm install --global yarn`


ref: https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install/#alternatives-stable

Answer (score 134):

Not remembering how i've installed yarn the command that worked for me was:

`yarn policies set-version`

This command updates the current yarn version to the latest stable.

From the documentation:

> Note that this command also is the preferred way to upgrade Yarn - it will work no matter how you originally installed it, which might sometimes prove difficult to figure out otherwise.

[Reference](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/policies/#toc-policies-set-version)

Comment: Its also worth noting that this command creates `.yarn/` and `.yarnrc`

Comment: It did not update Yarn globally, only in the current project.

Comment: This command didn't work for me, it return the error: ` error Couldn't find a package.json file in "/home/.."`

Comment: I guess it didn't work because I installed my `yarn` with `apt-get`. I think it is possible to know how you installed your package. For me, I do `npm list -g >filename.txt`, then I search the file for any package needed. For apt-get, I do `apt list --installed`, then I check the output for the package needed.

Answer (score 70):

On Linux, just run below command at terminal:

```
$ curl --compressed -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash
```

After do this, close the current terminal and open it again. And then, run below command to check yarn current version:

```
$ yarn --version
```

Comment: Works on OSX as well

Comment: Works on git bash but shows the same older version when you run `yarn --version` on command prompt.

Comment: @NirajNiroula You will need to re-open the terminal in order to see any changes.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work regardless of whether I opened a new terminal. For me `npm install --global yarn` worked in Ubuntu

Answer (score 48):

`yarn policies set-version`

will download the latest stable release

Referenced yarn docs
https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/policies/#toc-policies-set-version

Comment: Note that you can specify the version with this command too. e.g. `yarn policies set-version 1.21.0`

Comment: This command didn't work for me, it return the error `error Couldn't find a package.json file in "/home/.."`

Comment: This is typically used for setting a policy for a shared team project, not for updating/upgrading a global installation

Answer (score 39):

**For Windows users**

I usually upgrade Yarn with [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/).

```
choco upgrade yarn
```

Answer (score 33):

Works on all OS's

```
yarn set version latest
yarn set version from sources
```

Worked without the second line for me, but it is in the documentation for some reason.

[Reference](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/usage)

Comment: Be careful. It works but broke `global add` for me.

Comment: the 2nd line produces error `error An unexpected error occurred: "Release not found: from".`

Comment: Only `yarn set version latest` should be used, the second command use unstable version from git https://yarnpkg.com/cli/set/version/from/sources

Answer (score 23):

`npm install -g yarn` - solved the issue when nothing happened running `npm update --global yarn`.

Alternative method to update yarn: `curl --compressed -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash`.

Mac users with homebrew can run `brew upgrade yarn`.

More details [here](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/3042) and [here](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/3574).

Comment: If `npm update --global yarn` didn't work but `npm install -g yarn` did it's possible it wasn't installed by npm in the first place.

Comment: thanks, it worked for me. upgraded to yarn 1.22.4 from yarn 1.19.1

Comment: I had to remove Yarn from *Program Files (x86)* first before installing with `npm`.

Answer (score 19):

I had an outdated symlink that was preventing me from accessing the proper bin. I had also recently gone through a node upgrade which means a lot of my newer bins were available in a different folder with what i think was a lower priority

Here is what worked for me:

```
yarn -v 
> 1.15.2

which yarn
> /Users/lfender/.yarn/bin/yarn 

rm -rf /Users/lfender/.yarn/bin/yarn
npm uninstall --global yarn; npm install --global yarn

> + yarn@1.16.0
> added 1 package in 0.179s

which yarn
> /Users/lfender/.nvm/versions/node/v12.2.0/bin/yarn

yarn -v
> 1.16.0
```

If you are not using NVM, the location of your bin installs are likely to be unique to your system

From there, I've switched to doing `yarn policies set-version` as outlined here https://stackoverflow.com/a/55278430/1426788 to define my yarn version at the repo level

Answer (score 19):

According to https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install#updating-to-the-latest-versions

```
yarn set version <version>
```

For example to upgrade yarn v1.22.4 to v1.22.10:

```
yarn set version 1.22.10
```

Comment: Or latest: `yarn set version stable`

Answer (score 10):

I updated yarn on my Ubuntu by running the following command from my terminal

> curl --compressed -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash

source:`https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/self-update`

Comment: Thank you Merabi. The source is really useful.

Answer (score 7):

1. Add Yarn Package Directory:

`curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list`

2. Install Yarn:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yarn`

Please note that the last command will upgrade yarn to latest version if package already installed.

For more info you can check the docs: [yarn installation](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#debian-stable)

Comment: This solution worked for me on Windows 10 ubuntu WSL  terminal with zsh.

Comment: This solution works if you had installed `yarn` with `apt-get`. It worked for me on `Ubuntu 16.04`

Answer (score 6):

If you already have yarn `1.x` and you want to upgrade to yarn 2. You need to do something a bit different:

```sh
yarn set version berry
```

Where [`berry`](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry) is the code name for yarn version 2. See this migration guide [here](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install#per-project-install) for more info.

Answer (score 4):

I tried at first

```
yarn policies set-version
```

Then it directed me to run

```
yarn set version stable
```

You should implement them in order, the first command will download your current yarn version and update .yarnrc after that running the second command will upgrade yarn successfully to the latest stable version

Answer (score 1):

I tried all of the above solutions in Jenkins pipeline which needs the latest yarn.
Finally, this worked for me.

1. Run yarn policies set-version in the git repo
2. This will generate .yarn/releases/yarn-X.X.X.js file and .yarnrc file. Push both of these files in the Git repo.
3. Now build and all the yarn commands will use the yarn-X.X.X version.

**Note**: This is helpful when you don't have root access to npm install -g yarn.

Answer (score 1):

```
npm i -g yarn
```

This should update your yarn version. Check version with `yarn -v` or `yarn --version`.

Comment: yarn -v will be effective at new terminal tab

Answer (score 1):

```
yarn policies set-version --rc
```

As per the yarn documentation to update yarn to latest version we should run the above command. Check version with `yarn -v` or `yarn --version`.

Ref : https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/policies/#toc-policies-set-version

Answer (score 0):

> yarn policies set-version

Use the above command in powershell to upgrade your current yarn version to Latest.It will download the latest yarn release

Answer (score 0):

> yarn policies set-version

this upgraded my yarn version from **1.22.5** to **1.22.10**

Answer (score 0):

If You want to upgrade your yarn version from 1.22.5 to 1.22.10

> yarn policies set-version

Answer (score 0):

This work for me to change yarn version `0.32` git to `1.22.5`

https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/shell/yarn+0.32+git+ubuntu

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29853964)

Comment: Although the format needs improvements, this answer is the only one worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade to latest version of yarn, run the below command on your terminal.

"yarn set version latest -g"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on yarn version 2 and above. Then you can run `yarn set version stable` to upgrade to the latest stable version.

You can read more at the [docs](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/usage#upgrading-yarn-itself)

Answer (score -9):

Since you already have yarn installed and only want to upgrade/update. you can simply use

`yarn self-update`

Find ref here https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/self-update

Comment: This is not a solution. If you checked the page, it says "Note: self-update is not available. See policies for enforcing versions within a project"

Comment: why would they even have the page? that's confusing.

Comment: Why is this even a page. And it is a Google ranking page too. Ughh..