# I 'm trying to 'rails server' and I have problem installing webpack and yarn

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to 'rails server' and I get this :

```
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-5.4.0/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:103:in `rescue in load': Webpacker configuration file not found /home/hossein/Downloads/Projects/RubyProjects/work/demo/config/webpacker.yml. Please run rails webpacker:install Error: No such file or directory @ rb_check_realpath_internal - /home/hossein/Downloads/Projects/RubyProjects/work/demo/config/webpacker.yml (RuntimeError)
```

and when I install webpack with "bundle exec rails webpacker:install", I get this:

Webpacker requires Yarn ">=1 <3" and you are using 0.32+git
Please upgrade Yarn https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/
Exiting!

and then : "npm install --global yarn"

I get this :

```
> yarn@1.22.10 preinstall /home/hossein/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/yarn
> :; (node ./preinstall.js > /dev/null 2>&1 || true)
```

/home/hossein/.npm-global/bin/yarn -> /home/hossein/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js
/home/hossein/.npm-global/bin/yarnpkg -> /home/hossein/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js

- yarn@1.22.10
  updated 1 package in 2.123s

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. sudo npm install -g npm
2. sudo npm install -g yarn

Answer (score 1):

[This article](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-18.04/) pointed me in the right direction.. but my fix was a bit more involved. After these steps, closing the shell and restarting the system worked for me. Upgrade credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50460573/8834358)

**NOTE** that verifying the npm version didn't work until I restarted everything.

Enable the nodesource repo:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
```

Install Node.js and npm:

```
sudo apt install nodejs
```

Verify it works:

```
node --version
npm --version
```

Upgrade yarn:

```
curl --compressed -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash
```